# Testing multiple subdirectories with Travis-Ci

Tags: travis-ci

I would like to use Travis to test two projects in one Repo.
The GIT-repository's directories currently look like this:

root
|
-- server-application
|
-- client-application

My server-application is built using the Playframework and the client-application is built for Android. In my case, it makes more sense to put both projects in one git-repository, but I still want to test the server and the Android application separately (or at least make the tests run for both projects).

The main problems I see here:

- PlayFramework uses SBT and Android uses Gradle.
- I dont think the server-application will use the same testing framework as the client-application.